# When I fetch data from Local Storage, I get error. Next.Js/React.Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I fetched data from local storage which contains "title" and "image path".

I used useEffect to get the local storage data and saved it in useState.

Problem is that when the page is first rendered, the array is empty so I get an error.
How can I go about this?

```
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getItems = localStorage.getItem("action");
    if (getItems) {
      const actionFavorites = JSON.parse(getItems);
      setCategory(actionFavorites);
    }
  }, []);
```

```
  <Wrapper>
      <Navbar link="/" logo="Retour" />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="imgContainer">
          <Image
            src={category[current].image}
            alt="main image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="contain"
          />
        </div>
  </ Wrapper>
```

I get the error on "category[current].image".
I think it's an easy fix but I am still a beginner and I have been stuck here for a while.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the localStorage.getItem("action") value look like? what error are you receiving on the browser?

Comment: You should use a ternary to see whether `category` is defined, or on the first render you'll get a "cannot read properties of undefined" error.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me. Now it's working! I followed the instructon of the person who answered below. 

Thank you again for taking your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could render the `<Image>` conditionally. [Learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on official docs.

Wrapper block could be written as:
I have added `{category && <Element></Element>}`, so that it could render conditionally.

```
  <Wrapper>
      <Navbar link="/" logo="Retour" />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="imgContainer">
          {category && <Image
            src={category[current].image}
            alt="main image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="contain"
          />}
        </div>
  </Wrapper>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. First I got an error but then I added {category[current]...} then it renders without an error. Thank you so much for your help!